# How we can add Mesibo chat in WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, mesibo

what will be the best method to integrate Mesibo chat sdk in WordPress website.
https://mesibo.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mesibo Javascript API to add chat to WordPress. There is no ready sample that I know of but it is easy to integrate and you can start here https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/get-started/